# Selenium/capybara: uncheck() does not work in chrome web driver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, web, capybara, driver

I am using Selenium/capybara uncheck("permission_set_item_edit_permission") to uncheck a box. (see sample HTML code). It works fine with firefox. But chrome driver does not uncheck the box. It seems it finds the element but uncheck does not work. Is there something special about chrome driver? In general I have found chrome to be more finnicky than FF.

```
<tr class="entity">
      <th class="bold">Item1</th>
      <td>
            <div class="permission-records">
              <label>&nbsp;</label>
              <label>&nbsp;</label>
              <label><input name="permission_set[item_edit_permission]" type="hidden" value="0"><input id="permission_set_item_edit_permission" name="permission_set[item_edit_permission]" type="checkbox" value="1"> Edit Global</label>
            </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: do you get an error or does it just not do anything? Also, in your HTML the checkbox isn't actually checked so I wouldn't expect uncheck to do anything

Comment: Also, a label element may only contain one labelable control, so having two input elements inside of one label element is technically illegal HTML.  Chrome may be treating the illegal HTML differently than FF.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried with capybara 2 and it works with that (I was using capybara 1.1.2). I will talk to the developer about the illegal input element that you mentioned.

Comment: Wow, Capybara 1.1.2 is from 2011 - probably want to update a bit more regularly than that :)

Comment: I know :-). We have a huge test suite and our team has been trying to migrate everything to capy2 but it's been a bit slow. Meanwhile we have to continue with capy1.

Answer (score 0):

Considering this resolved after Thomas Walpole's comments.